# jQuery each loop doubles the results found

Tags: jquery, loops, each

I'm trying to figure out how to solve this problem;

Here is my html:

```
<div id="result">
  <div class="selectable" data-id="1"> Item 1 </div>
  <div class="selectable" data-id="2"> Item 2 </div>
  <div class="selectable" data-id="3"> Item 3 </div>
  <div class="selectable" data-id="4"> Item 4 </div>
  <div class="selectable" data-id="5"> Item 5 </div>
</div>

<button class="insert">Insert</button>

<div id="master"></div>
```

and here is JS:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#result").on('click', '.selectable', function() {
          if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
              $(this).removeClass('active');
          } else {
              $(this).addClass('active');
          }
      });

      $(".insert").on('click', function() {
          var html = '';
          $("#result .active").each(function() {
              var id = $(this).data('id');
              html += '<div class="rows"> ' + id + ' </div>';
          });
          $("#master").prepend(html)
      });
  });
```

Selecting and deselecting ".selectable" items works fine, but for some reason if two items are selected, html inserted into "master" div is always doubled, so I get 4 items instead of two.

I think the problem is with each loop, If I do something like `console.log($("#result .highlite").length);`
just before loop, correct number of selected items is shown.

Comment: I ran your code snippet and it seems okay to me if you want to stack the already "Inserted" items. However, if you want to completely replace the already inserted items, instead of using the `.prepend`, try with the `.html` method: `$("#master").html(html)`. Is that what you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to prepend items, since I already have some inside master div.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you should be replacing the html each time the button is clicked

Try changing"

```
$("#master").prepend(html)
```

To

```
$("#master").html(html)
```

Comment: No, actually, I already have some items inside master div, and I want to prepend them, not replace them.

Comment: create a demo that reproduces problem

Answer (score -1):

you can try below jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $("#result").on('click', '.selectable', function() {
      $(".selectable").removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');          
      });

      $(".insert").on('click', function() {
          var html = '';
          $("#result .active").each(function() {
              var id = $(this).data('id');
              html += '<div class="rows"> ' + id + ' </div>';
          });
          $("#master").prepend(html)
      });
  });
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/9facre9e/)

Hope it will solve your issue.

Thanks

Comment: why negative.. ??